# How to get manufacturer attribute value on Checkout success page?

Tags: checkout, orders, product-attribute

I am trying to get the attribute values for products in an order and show them on the checkout success page.

So far I have been able to get SKU, NAME, but MANUFACTURER won't show any value...

Here is the code I am using to get the items from the checkout session:

```
<?php //
    $products = array();
    $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    $_order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);

    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order */
    foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems()  as $item) {
        $info['sku'] = trim($item->getSku());
        $info['qty'] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $info['name'] = $item->getName();
        $info['manufacturer'] = $item->getManufacturer();

        $products[] = $info;


    }

    $config['productInfos'] = $products;
?>
```

And to echo the values:

```
                            <?php foreach ($config['productInfos'] as $product): ?>
                                <?php echo trim(stripslashes(htmlentities($product['manufacturer']))); ?>
                                <?php echo trim(stripslashes(htmlentities($product['name']))); ?>,
                                <?php echo trim(stripslashes(htmlentities($product['sku']))); ?>,
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

`Sales order item object` do **not save Manufacturer attribute** to **sales_flat_order_item table.**
If you want `get Manufacturer` then you need `load Product by $item->getProductId();`

Like:

```
$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

$info['manufacturer'] = $product->getManufacturer();
```

Comment: Thankyou for your comments I will give it a try and post back...

Comment: I get an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId()`

Comment: hey check again.....

Comment: Sorry but I can't get past this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId()`